# Some old and all new published RemoteApps aren't appearing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

So, here's our situation. We've had a RemoteApp environment for 2+ years, and I've recently been given access to help manage it. I've been trying to get a new app published so some off-site people can access an app I installed onto the host server. I published it, and it looks fine there, and it's set to allow it to appear in RD Web Access. I also checked permissions, and at least for now it's set to allow anyone who can access the collection access it, and that's fine until I get a new AD group created to manage access for it.

However, when I publish the app, I get an error saying it can't publish it on one server. The server it's throwing the error for isn't a host server, but it contains all of the other RD services (RDCM, RDCB, RDL, RDG, RDM) so it's in the collection. I'm GUESSING that this error is what's preventing the app from being fully published and made available to RD connections, but I could be off base there. I've also checked through the pre-existing RemoteApps and I noticed that another one that I should have access to also isn't showing in my list, so this issue looks like it's been around for at least a little while.

Our environment is pretty basic, but here it is:

```
 Server1 - Hosts all the RDS related services, including Remote Desktop Management, RemoteApp and Desktop Connection Management, Remote Desktop Connection Broker, Remote Desktop Licensing, and Remote Desktop Gateway
 Server2 - RemoteApp Host
 Server3 - VDI host
```

I've checked through all of the RDP/TS related logs on Server1 and Server2, but I'm not seeing any errors popping out at me. And to be clear, any RemoteApps that had previously been published and available to me are still available and working. But any newly published RemoteApps, as well as at least one that had previously been published, isn't. I also added myself to an AD group that should have made a few more RemoteApps show up, but either I didn't wait long enough for AD LAN replication to occur (so unlikely), or that's broken as well.

I've checked the RemoteApps listing via the published web portal, as well as via my already configured RemoteApp connection in Win10. I'm seeing the same content in both locations.

As far as the local groups, the following groups on Server1 have the following memberships:

```
RDS Endpoint Servers - All 3 servers
RDS Management Servers - Server1, Network Service, RDMS, TScPubRPC, Tssdis
RDS Remote Access Servers - Server1
```

Also, Get-RDRemoteApp lists all of the same published apps I see when going through Server Manager, including the ones that I don't see when going through my RemoteApp connections. And they all say ShowInWebAccess = True. And I know from a thread on Technet that there's some sort of alias character limit, but the alias for one of the new apps is only 9 characters, and some that are working are over 20 characters, so that's not it.

If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them, since I'm kind of at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your new application is installed on all RD Session Hosts in the collection. When you publish, the configuration for the Remote App is automatically pushed to all RD Session Host servers that are members of the Session Collection.

> You can run this PowerShell to list all RD Session Host servers in a collection:
>
> `Get-RDSessionHost -CollectionName <Collection Name> -ConnectionBroker <Server FQDN>`

You can also try publishing a test application that is known to be on all servers (like notepad.exe) to see if that works or not:

`New-RDRemoteApp -CollectionName <Collection Name> -ConnectionBroker <Server FQDN> -Alias "NotepadTest" -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" -ShowInWebAccess 1 -DisplayName "NotepadTest"`

Comment: There's only a single host for this collection (Server2), and it's definitely installed there. (And the command you listed verified that.)

Comment: Do you get the same error when trying to publish with the PowerShell method? Please verify and copy the error message here. It does not make sense that it would try to publish to a server that is not a member of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like we got it figured out. The SSL cert had expired, but nobody noticed because it was replaced on the proxy, so nobody was getting an error when they were connecting. It just hadn't been replaced on the deployment itself. Once that cert was replaced we were able to publish new RemoteApps without any errors, and they're showing in the portal and working correctly.